# Wlan is not detected in Haier Y11b

Tags: 16.04, wireless, realtek-wireless

I am totally new to Linux. Govt awarded me [Haier Y11B](http://www.haier.com/pk/products/pc/Tablet_PC/y11b_ext.shtml) whose wlan is not detected (let alone malfunction). We are 5 Students determined to say goodbye to Windows and have installed Ubuntu with same problems.

I did some research, I installed ndisgtk and tried installing proprietary drivers, no avail!

Here are some command outputs:

```
$ sudo lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
cdc_ether              16384  0
usbnet                 45056  1 cdc_ether
mii                    16384  1 usbnet
nls_utf8               16384  0
isofs                  40960  0
drbg                   32768  1
ansi_cprng             16384  0
dm_crypt               28672  1
intel_rapl             20480  0
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
intel_powerclamp       16384  0
coretemp               16384  0
kvm_intel             172032  0
kvm                   544768  1 kvm_intel
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
aesni_intel           167936  5741
rtsx_usb_ms            20480  0
memstick               20480  1 rtsx_usb_ms
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
lrw                    16384  1 aesni_intel
gf128mul               16384  1 lrw
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
ablk_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 20480  2873 ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel,ablk_helper
serio_raw              16384  0
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     53248  1
snd_hda_codec_realtek    86016  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    77824  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_soc_rt5640        114688  0
snd_soc_ssm4567        16384  0
snd_soc_rl6231         16384  1 snd_soc_rt5640
elan_i2c               36864  0
snd_soc_core          212992  2 snd_soc_rt5640,snd_soc_ssm4567
kxcjk_1013             20480  0
snd_compress           20480  1 snd_soc_core
industrialio_triggered_buffer    16384  1 kxcjk_1013
ac97_bus               16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_pcm_dmaengine      16384  1 snd_soc_core
intel_pch_thermal      16384  0
snd_hda_intel          40960  5
snd_hda_codec         135168  4 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_core           73728  5 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
uvcvideo               90112  0
snd_pcm               106496  7 snd_soc_rt5640,snd_soc_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm_dmaengine,snd_hda_core
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         28672  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_core         36864  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_v4l2
v4l2_common            16384  1 videobuf2_v4l2
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
videodev              176128  4 uvcvideo,v4l2_common,videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2
ndiswrapper           286720  0
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
media                  24576  2 uvcvideo,videodev
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
input_leds             16384  0
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
mei_me                 36864  0
lpc_ich                24576  0
snd                    81920  23 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_core,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device,snd_compress
mei                    98304  1 mei_me
soundcore              16384  1 snd
processor_thermal_device    16384  0
intel_soc_dts_iosf     16384  1 processor_thermal_device
int3403_thermal        16384  0
snd_soc_sst_acpi       16384  0
mac_hid                16384  0
dw_dmac                16384  0
dw_dmac_core           24576  1 dw_dmac
int3400_thermal        16384  0
8250_dw                16384  0
acpi_thermal_rel       16384  1 int3400_thermal
int3402_thermal        16384  0
spi_pxa2xx_platform    24576  0
i2c_designware_platform    16384  0
int340x_thermal_zone    16384  3 int3402_thermal,processor_thermal_device,int3403_thermal
i2c_designware_core    20480  1 i2c_designware_platform
acpi_als               16384  0
acpi_pad               24576  0
kfifo_buf              16384  2 industrialio_triggered_buffer,acpi_als
industrialio           61440  4 industrialio_triggered_buffer,acpi_als,kxcjk_1013,kfifo_buf
parport_pc             32768  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
autofs4                40960  2
uas                    24576  0
usb_storage            69632  2 uas
rtsx_usb_sdmmc         28672  0
rtsx_usb               24576  2 rtsx_usb_sdmmc,rtsx_usb_ms
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 49152  0
i915                 1208320  4
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
drm_kms_helper        155648  1 i915
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
drm                   364544  5 i915,drm_kms_helper
ahci                   36864  3
libahci                32768  1 ahci
sdhci_acpi             16384  0
video                  40960  1 i915
sdhci                  45056  1 sdhci_acpi
i2c_hid                20480  0
hid                   118784  3 i2c_hid,hid_generic,usbhid
fjes                   28672  0

$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0bda:5830 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0bda:b720 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:5830 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 05e3:0718 Genesys Logic, Inc. IDE/SATA Adapter
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 04d9:e200 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 013: ID 12d1:14db Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E353/E3131
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04b3:310c IBM Corp. Wheel Mouse
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: enx0c5b8f279a64
       serial: 0c:5b:8f:27:9a:64
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=cdc_ether driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=CDC Ethernet Device ip=192.168.8.100 link=yes multicast=yes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are lucky because you have an ethernet connection. With the ethernet attached, please open a terminal Ctrl+Alt+t and run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge ndisgtk ndiswrapper*
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git
```

Your wireless device is this: *ID 0bda:b720 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.*

A Google search finds this: https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723bu I downoaded and built the driver and I see that it covers your device:

```
alias:          usb:v0BDApB720d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFiscFFipFFin*
```

Let's build it according to the instructions:

```
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723bu.git
cd rtl8723bu
gedit Makefile
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit. Find the line that contains

```make
EXTRA_CFLAGS += -DCONFIG_CONCURRENT_MODE
```

and insert a `#` symbol at the beginning of that line. This comments that line and disables concurrent mode. Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor. Next, continue:

```
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe -v 8723bu
```

You have compiled the driver for your current running kernel only. When Update Manager installs a later one, also known as linux-image, after the requested reboot, re-compile:

```
cd  rtl8723bu
make clean
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 8723bu
```

Please retain the file and these instructions for that time.

Comment: <pre>
I am extremely grateful to you sir, 
this solved my problem as I am posting this comment using wifi now. 

I don't know much about linux so I don't know how to post screen shot. 


I am waiting for next instruction :)

This solved 5 problems simultaneously because we are 5 guys getting rid of windows :) 

Should I ask a new question about the touch screen not working properly. 
by properly I mean it stops working.  
I can't post results due to characters limit
</pre>

Comment: Please start a new question about your touchscreen. Please see my edit above. If my answer has been helpful, please accept it: https://askubuntu.com/tour