# I am not getting full speed on wifi

Tags: networking, drivers, network-manager, internet

I have Haier y11b laptop.Recently I installed ubuntu on it. The wifi is not running on default drivers so google and I found this [haier y11b wifi drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/922211/wlan-is-not-detected-in-haier-y11b?newreg=02763d97b8fb476f95f958462cc759b4).
But after installing this driver my wifi is connected but the signal strength is poor. I am only getting 250kb of speed.While on windows 10 it is upto 4mbps.
Please help me. I don't want to switch to windows again. I have realtek 8723b card.
This command is showing me nothing output `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3`

`nmcli d show` command is giving following output:

---

Comment: Welcome, I guess you forgot to add the output of the *nmcli d show* command.

Comment: take a look at either https://askubuntu.com/questions/922211/wlan-is-not-detected-in-haier-y11b   or  https://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/how-do-i-get-a-realtek-rtl8723be-wireless-card-to-work